# java stringbuilder deleting a line

Tags: java, stringbuilder

So I have this problem. I have used StringBuilder and I am trying to create a display function using JOptionPane that will display a staff's name and pay. The display function also has to delete a line everytime a staff name is deleted from the system, as I do not want to have empty lines in my JOptionPane box. However, I cannot get it to display properly, as when I try to delete a staff name, it deletes  it's own staff name, as well as all the staff names that are before it in the list. staffDetails is a separate array that i have containing the staff's name and pay.
here is my code for displaying staff:

```
public static StringBuilder staffRecord= new StringBuilder();
  public static void displayrezStaffRecord(){
      int staffnumber=1;
      for (int n=0;n<staffDetails.length;n++){
          staffRecord.append(staffDetails[n].getStaffName());
          staffRecord.append("\t ");
          staffRecord.append(staffDetails[n].getPay());
          staffRecord.append(" \n ");
          staffnumber++;
          if (staffDetails[n].getStaffName()==null){
              menunumber--;
              staffRecord.delete(0,staffRecord.length());

          }

  }
      String finalresult= staffRecord.toString();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Staff_No       Staff_Name      Pay      \n" +finalresult);
  } 
}
```

Comment: So are you trying to delete the line breaks ?

Comment: Why are you adding it at all? You don't need to delete it if you don't add it. Check if it's null before adding.

Comment: @BasilBattikhi Yes, if I delete a staff's name, I get an empty line and I do not know how to move the staff number up by 1, as well as move the next record up by 1 line.

Comment: Also the problem stems from this: `staffRecord.delete(0,staffRecord.length());`. You delete all the contents of the `StringBuilder` from it's start up to it's total length. Makes total sense that it deletes everything.

Comment: @RealSkeptic yeah but well, in my delete method, i set it to null upon delete. So i thought that checking if there were any null's and deleting it from the Stringbuilder would help. however i am just plain lost now.

Comment: @Aris do u have any suggestions on how I could fix that? thanks

Comment: What is your condition on deleting an employee?

Comment: @Aris there is no condition. When I manually delete the employee's name from my deletename method, it sets the name and pay to null. Hence, I added in the if null condition, which is messing everything up.

Comment: So if you delete an employee you basically set it's name to null, correct?

Comment: @Aris yes correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best suggestion is to avoid having two operations done at the same time. Here your attempt to filter out your deleted employee while appending their data to the `StringBuilder`. Ideally, I would first filter out the employees and then use them to create my `String` output. With that in mind your method would look like:

```
public static void display() {

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

List<Employee> filtered = Arrays.stream(employees)
                                .filter(employee -> employee.getName() == null)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());


filtered.forEach(employee ->
    builder.append(employee.getName())
           .append("\t ")
           .append(employee.getPay())
           .append("\n "));

String output = builder.toString();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Staff_No       Staff_Name      Pay      \n" + output);
}
```

Assuming that you store your employees in an array of Employees, I would basically, stream that array filtering out all entries with a null name, collecting the results in a list.

With that list in hand, I would then go ahead to use the `StringBuilder` to construct my output message to be shown in the dialog. Note also here, that I do not see any point in having the `StringBuilder` be a static member of the class. You could very well have it within the context of the method.

With all the above in place, you have two very distinct actions here. One is to filter out all the unwanted entries, and the other being the actual construction of the output string.

Comment: Also note that there is no need to call `append()` of the builder instance each time. `append()` effectively returns the `StringBuilder` instance, which means that you can have chained calls to it.

Answer (score 1):

Just check for `null` and skip this staff. And the `staffnumber` should be 0 at first. Also you don't have to make `StringBuilder` a static member, just create new `StringBuilder`. (Or you will have to clear it every time you call this method)

```
public static void displayrezStaffRecord() {
    int staffnumber = 0;
    StringBuilder staffRecord= new StringBuilder();
    for (int n = 0; n < staffDetails.length; n++) {
        if (staffDetails[n].getStaffName() == null) {
            menunumber--;
            continue;
        }
        staffRecord.append(staffDetails[n].getStaffName());
        staffRecord.append("\t ");
        staffRecord.append(staffDetails[n].getPay());
        staffRecord.append(" \n ");
        staffnumber++;
    }
    String finalresult = staffRecord.toString();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Staff_No       Staff_Name      Pay      \n" + finalresult);
}
```

I don't know if it is because your code is not complete, I can't see anywhere you use the variable `staffnumber`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete only current staff and decrease staffnumber after deleting like the the following in your if statement:

```
   if (staffDetails[n].getStaffName()==null){
      menunumber--;
      staffRecord.delete(staffRecord.length()-4,staffRecord.length());
      staffnumber--;
   }
```